# Git clone with shorthand SSH URL

Tags: git, ssh

Trying to clone with full SSH URL, e.g., `git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo.git` fails with permission denied (publickey), but using shorthand SSH URL, e.g., `git clone git@bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo.git` works just fine. Furthermore, even doing something like the following fails:

```bash
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_mykey_ed25519; git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo.git'
```

**EDIT:**
I already have an entry of the following form in SSH config:

```
Host bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_mykey_ed25519
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: To understand what is going on compare `ssh -Tv bitbucket.org` with `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org`. I'm sure the problem is you haven't properly configured SSH to always use the user `git` with  `bitbucket.org`. The simplest fix is always use `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/`. Better fix is to configure SSH. Please show us the text of your `~/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `User git`:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_mykey_ed25519
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    User git
```

Now you can do

```
git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo.git
```

without setting user explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Because your SSH private key file  not having the default name **`[id_rsa]`** if you rename it to **`id_rsa`** it works.

#### Another solution if you don't like to rename it

Make file in .ssh Folder from terminal call config

```bash
touch config
```

Put path for SSH file on it and save it

```
Host bitbucket.org
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_mykey_ed25519
     User git
```

and try to clone again it works without any problem

```bash
git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo.git
```

Comment: I already had such an entry, please check my updated question.

Comment: @terett What operating system that you use? - for me it works without any problem in windows.  you can add User git  to config file and Host.